# dell poweredge 2850 backplane swap

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I just ordered a dell poweredge 2850. I am wondering if it is possible to replace its backplane with the sata backplane of a dell poweredge 2950.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, the backplanes are not swappable between the two units.